# Regarding Tag Badge

Tags: support, badges

506 reputations are with me but the tag badge is not yet seen.

> You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Wondering if any one could help

Answer (score 4):

Well, for one you only have 52 answers total, not the 80 per tag that are required by the badge.

The badge is awarded when you have 80 answers on questions with the same tag, and at least 400 reputation points earned among those 80 answers.